# Implicitly pass instance in vapi

Tags: vala, vapi

I am trying to write a VAPI for the `mongoc` library.

I have created some compact classes from struct with some functions associated with them.
For example `Client` looks like this:

```c
[Compact]
[CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_t", free_function = "mongoc_client_destroy", has_type_id = false)]
public class Client {

   [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_new")]
   public Client (string uri);
}
```

I need to bind also a bunch of the related functions.
I tried to bind them as instance methods, like this:

```c
[CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_get_database")]
public Database get_database (Client client, string dbname);
//Database is another compact class
```

So that the resulting is this:

```c
[CCode (cheader_filename = "mongoc.h")]
namespace Mongo {
   [Compact]
   [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_t", free_function = "mongoc_client_destroy", has_type_id = false)]
   public class Client {

      [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_new")]
      public Client (string uri);

      [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_get_database")]
      public Database get_database (Client client, string dbname);
   }
}
```

I wanted it to take the first `client` parameter as the calling instance.
Instead of this:

```c
var client = new Client ("uri");
var db = client.get_database (client, "test");
//client is redundant
```

Im trying to get this:

```c
var client = new Client ("uri");
var db = client.get_database ("test");
//The Client instance is passed implicitly
```

I tried using `this`, static methods, `instance_pos` and other tweaks but I didn't find a way to get it working in that way.

Is it possible to pass the instance implicitly as a parameter in Vala?
If so, how can I bind a VAPI in a way that the instance is passed implicitly without redundancy?

Comment: Some years ago I also started with binding mongodb, but never got around to finishing it. Perhaps some of this is helpful: https://github.com/mickeyl/mops/blob/master/vala/vapi/libmongoc-1.0.vapi

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I actually finished (kinda) the vapi. The  bindings are in this repository: https://github.com/bynect/mongo-vapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C API for [`mongoc_client_get_database()`](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/mongoc_client_get_database.html) shows the function signature is:

`mongoc_database_t * mongoc_client_get_database (mongoc_client_t *client, const char *name);`

So the `monogc_client_t` is passed explicitly in the C API. In Vala this is automatically generated as the instance argument in the C code. You just need to drop the explicit argument, `Client client`, from the VAPI:

```cs
[CCode (cheader_filename = "mongoc.h")]
namespace Mongo {
   [Compact]
   [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_t", free_function = "mongoc_client_destroy", has_type_id = false)]
   public class Client {

      [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_new")]
      public Client (string uri);

      [CCode (cname = "mongoc_client_get_database")]
      public Database get_database (string dbname);
   }
}
```